# Attach a related object, to the newly created object using django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got a Model looking something like this

```
class SomeModel(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    some_info = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

There can exist a lot of these without a User attached. But at some point I might want to attach a user to some of them.
I don't know exactly where I should do this though. I have this serializer that works fine for creating users:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username', 'password')
            write_only_fields = ('password',)

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
            user = super(UserSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
            user.set_password(attrs['password'])
            user.save()
            return user
```

But where is the correct place to connect it to an already existing `SomeModel`? Preferrably with easy permission handling. (APIView?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can… I guess your point is to attach a user on the creation of your “SomeModel” new object. You do this on your view where you create the new object, not the user, the “someModel” object, I give you a quick example:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class SomeModelListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Api List and Create SomeModel Objects
    """
    model = SomeModel
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user = self.request.user
```

Hook it up to your URL and everytime you create a new SomeModel object in your API, the user will be the one creating it… on your “pre_save” method, you can apply all the logic you want.

And offcourse the serializer:

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.Field(source='user.username', label="user")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user', 'some_info')
```

Hope this helps

**Edit on your comment**

I think there are two ways if you want to connect SomeModel to your new User created.

You have a view for creating a user, in the example before it had "pre_save" method.

You ApiView to create the user, updated or deleted also have a "post_save" method. So create your user and in the post_method put your logic to hook it up to the "SomeModel" object that you want.

```
class UserListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Api List and Create User Objects and hook it to SomeModel objects
    """
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
        somemodel_object = SomeModel.object.get(pk=1)
        somemodel_object.user = obj
        somemodel_object.save()
```

this is one way, and you also have pre_save if you want to do something before save the user or post_save as you see here or pre_delete or post_delete... play around.

The second choice would be signals, you send a signal when saving the user and catch it on your SomeModel and do some logic there, but i found this more messy, but as you like:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

This helps?

Comment: I think I phrased my question a bit bad, I actually have a lot of `SomeModel` which has no `User` attached to them. But I want to be able to press a button "Create user" on the detail view of `SomeModel` which first creates a `User` and then connects this new `User` to the specific `SomeModel` that already exists.

I solved it almost like in your example already, but with User creation instead :)

Comment: I updated my answer, if you think this solve your issue, mark it right and vote up :P, if not, let me know to see if i can help